# Allow user to select a folder on the device which has a list of sub-folders (several deep) and finally a folder with images files to retrieve

Tags: android, file, uri

I am using ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocumentTree() to allow the user to select the folder where they copied several folders which have a list of image files (the image files may be several folders deep from the folder they selected). I need to search for a known folder name and retrieve the image files.  I'm trying to do it so that the user does not have to select each of the image files. I can use other data to search and find the correct folder(s) and image files once the "root" folder is know.  The problem I am having is trying to convert the Uri returned from the ActivityResult into a File (directory) to search for the sub-folder. The resulting "File" is not a valid File.  Maybe this is not the correct way to do this?  I would like to support Build.VERSION_CODES.Q and earlier versions of Android.  Is this the wrong approach?

Here is what I have tried.  In this sample, I'm not doing anything yet with the files since I'm not getting them.

Fragment

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    mViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(ImportImagesViewModel.class);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("");
    selectImageFolder.launch(uri);
}


ActivityResultLauncher<Uri> selectImageFolder = registerForActivityResult(
        new ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocumentTree(), new ActivityResultCallback<Uri>()
        {
            @Override
            public void onActivityResult(Uri result)
            {
                try {
                    if (result != null) {

                        for (MetalItem metalItem : MetalsGlobal.GetMetalItems()) {
                            getImageFilesFromImageFolder(new File(result.getPath()), metalItem.Source, metalItem.OrderNumber, String.valueOf(metalItem.OrderItemNumber));
                        }
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Nothing selected...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } catch (Exception x) {
                    Log.e("Import Inventory Get File Launcher", x.getMessage(), x);
                    Toast.makeText(requireContext(), x.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });


private void getImageFilesFromImageFolder(File folder, @NonNull String source, @NonNull String orderNumber, @NonNull String itemNumber)
{
    if (folder == null ||
            source.length() == 0 ||
            orderNumber.length() == 0 ||
            itemNumber.length() == 0)
        return;

    File[] sourceFolders = folder.listFiles();
    if (sourceFolders == null) return;

    for (File sourceFolder : sourceFolders) {
        if (!sourceFolder.isDirectory())
            continue;
        if (!sourceFolder.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(source))
            continue;
        File[] orderNumberFolders = sourceFolder.listFiles();
        if (orderNumberFolders == null) return;

        for (File orderNumberFolder : orderNumberFolders) {
            if (!orderNumberFolder.isDirectory())
                continue;
            if (!orderNumberFolder.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(orderNumber))
                continue;
            File[] itemNumberFolders = orderNumberFolder.listFiles();
            if (itemNumberFolders == null) return;

            for (File itemNumberFolder : itemNumberFolders) {
                if (!itemNumberFolder.isDirectory())
                    continue;
                if (!itemNumberFolder.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(itemNumber))
                    continue;
                // Here should be the image files
                File[] imageFiles = itemNumberFolder.listFiles();
                if (imageFiles == null) return;

                for (File imageFile : imageFiles) {
                    if (!(imageFile.isFile() && imageFile.canRead()))
                        return;
                    try {
                        Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(imageFile.toString());
                        int blah = imageUri.toString().length();
                    } catch (Exception x) {
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, I would prefer that the user not need to install another app to do this..

Comment: "The resulting "File" is not a valid File" -- that is because you are not working with files on the filesystem. The user can choose other document sources. Use `DocumentFile.fromTreeUri()` to get a `DocumentFile` for the tree `Uri` that you get from `onActivityResult()`. `DocumentFile` offers a similar API to `File`, but works with documents and trees from the Storage Access Framework.

Comment: aha.  I saw DocumentFile.fromUri() but missed the DocumentFile.fromTreeUri().  Thanks a lot CommonsWare.  I'm curious if there is a better way to do this.  I'm not too concerned with the overhead as this should be a one time usage once the app is installed.

Comment: "I'm curious if there is a better way to do this" -- `DocumentFile` isn't super-quick, but that is because it is doing a lot of `ContentProvider` queries, and that is not super-quick. Once you have something working, it is possible that you could look at the `DocumentFile` code, identify the specific queries that they are doing, and do them yourself in a more optimized form.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the suggestion from CommonsWare this is the revised method which works exactly like I need.

```
private void processImageFolder(DocumentFile folder, MetalItem metalItem)
{
    String source = metalItem.Source;
    String orderNumber = metalItem.OrderNumber;
    String itemNumber = String.valueOf(metalItem.OrderItemNumber);
    if (folder == null ||
            source.length() == 0 ||
            orderNumber.length() == 0 ||
            itemNumber.length() == 0)
        return;

    DocumentFile[] sourceFolders = folder.listFiles();

    for (DocumentFile sourceFolder : sourceFolders) {
        if (!sourceFolder.isDirectory())
            continue;
        if (!Objects.requireNonNull(sourceFolder.getName()).equalsIgnoreCase(source))
            continue;
        DocumentFile[] orderNumberFolders = sourceFolder.listFiles();

        for (DocumentFile orderNumberFolder : orderNumberFolders) {
            if (!orderNumberFolder.isDirectory())
                continue;
            if (!Objects.requireNonNull(orderNumberFolder.getName()).equalsIgnoreCase(orderNumber))
                continue;
            DocumentFile[] itemNumberFolders = orderNumberFolder.listFiles();

            for (DocumentFile itemNumberFolder : itemNumberFolders) {
                if (!itemNumberFolder.isDirectory())
                    continue;
                if (!Objects.requireNonNull(itemNumberFolder.getName()).equalsIgnoreCase(itemNumber))
                    continue;

                // Here should be the image files
                DocumentFile[] imageFiles = itemNumberFolder.listFiles();

                for (DocumentFile imageFile : imageFiles) {
                    if (!(imageFile.isFile() && imageFile.canRead()))
                        return;
                    try {
                        loadItemImage(metalItem, imageFile);
                    } catch (Exception x) {
                        return;
                    }
                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```